# Security Exception: Permission 'android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE' not granted

Tags: java, android, location, securityexception

I am developing an app in which I am tracking location using the tower location.
So I am using the geo location api to track the location and accessing the phone state to get the network details.

This worked well, suddenly it started giving the security exception for LOCATION_HARDWARE permission.

I also tried to give the permission in manifest as well as requesting the permission runtime. But at runtime it asks for only location and the phone state permission not for the location_hardware permission. And then it crashes with security exception.

I am not getting for which purpose it is asking for the location_hardware permission.

I am stuck up here.

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setUpUI();
 public void setUpUI()
    {
     TrackingJob.schedulePeriodic(); // crashing here
    }
    }
    }
}
```

Tracking Job :

```
    public class TrackingJob extends Job {

    static final String TAG = "tracking";

    @NonNull
    @Override
    protected Result onRunJob(Params params) {

        Intent pi = new Intent(getContext(), GetLocationService.class);

        getContext().startService(pi);

        return Result.SUCCESS;
    }

    public static void schedulePeriodic() {
        new JobRequest.Builder(TrackingJob.TAG)
                .setPeriodic(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15), TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(15))
                .setUpdateCurrent(true)
                .setPersisted(true)
                .build()
                .schedule();

    }
}
```

GetLocationServer :

```
public class GetLocationService extends IntentService {
    String networkSubType = "";
    SessionData mSessionData;
    private SharedPreferences preferences;

    public GetLocationService() {
        super("GetLocationService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(GetLocationService.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(GetLocationService.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            mSessionData = new SessionData(GetLocationService.this);

            Calendar calendarSet = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calendarNow = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendarSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 7); // hour
            calendarSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00); // minute
            calendarSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // second

            Calendar calendarEnd = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendarEnd.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 20); // hour
            calendarEnd.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00); // minute
            calendarEnd.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0); // second


            SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            System.out.println(calendarNow.getTime());
// Output "Wed Sep 26 14:23:28 EST 2012"

            String currentTime = format1.format(calendarNow.getTime());
            System.out.println(currentTime);

            if (calendarNow.compareTo(calendarSet) >= 0 && calendarNow.compareTo(calendarEnd) <= 0) {

                TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) GetLocationService.this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
                GsmCellLocation cellLocation = (GsmCellLocation) telephonyManager.getCellLocation();

                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) GetLocationService.this.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);//?????????
                NetworkInfo activeNetInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

                if (cellLocation != null) {

                    int cellid = cellLocation.getCid();
                    int celllac = cellLocation.getLac();

                    if (activeNetInfo != null) {
                        networkSubType = activeNetInfo.getSubtypeName();
                    }

                    String networkOperator = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperator();

                    int mcc = Integer.parseInt(networkOperator.substring(0, 3));
                    int mnc = Integer.parseInt(networkOperator.substring(3));

                    String networkOperatorName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();
                    int type = telephonyManager.getNetworkType();


                    Log.d("CellLocation", cellLocation.toString());
                    Log.d("GSM CELL ID", String.valueOf(cellid));
                    Log.d("GSM Location Code", String.valueOf(celllac));


                    Log.d("MCC", String.valueOf(mcc));
                    Log.d("MNC", String.valueOf(mnc));
                    Log.d("NetworkOperatorName", networkOperatorName);
                    Log.d("radioType", String.valueOf(type));
                    Log.d("Network subtype name", networkSubType);


                    AddLocationAsyncTask addLocationAsyncTask = new AddLocationAsyncTask(GetLocationService.this);
                    addLocationAsyncTask.execute(mSessionData.getString("user_id", ""), String.valueOf(cellid), String.valueOf(celllac), String.valueOf(mcc), String.valueOf(mnc),
                            networkOperatorName, networkSubType, currentTime);

                //    LocationUtility.scheduleJob(getApplicationContext());

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I solve this? Please help with this.

Thank you..

EDIT : Runtime permissions:

```
public class StartUpActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    public int mShortAnimationDuration = 5000;
    private Button btnRegister,btnLogin;
    private final static int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION = 10;
    private SessionData mSessionData;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_up);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mSessionData = new SessionData(StartUpActivity.this);


        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(StartUpActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(StartUpActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(StartUpActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(StartUpActivity.this, Manifest.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(StartUpActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,Manifest.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION);

        }
        else {

            if(!mSessionData.getString("user_id","").equals(""))
            {
                Intent i = (new Intent(StartUpActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
            else {

                setUpUI();
                listeners();
            }
        }
    }

    public void setUpUI()
    {

        relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
        btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_login);
        btnRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_register);
    }

    public void listeners()
    {

        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = (new Intent(StartUpActivity.this, SignUpActivity.class));
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();

            }
        });

        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent i = (new Intent(StartUpActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {

            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION: {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    setUpUI();
                    listeners();

                } else {

                    CommonUtils.showAlert(StartUpActivity.this,"Please accept the permissions to proceed.",getString(R.string.app_name));
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(StartUpActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,Manifest.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE},
                            MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_ACCESS_LOCATION);
                }
                return;
            }     
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest permissions:

```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network"/>
```

Comment: You shouldn't ask for the permissions again in the `onRequestPermissionsResult `. This callback is for you to trigger your code according to the permission result, not to ask it again, Try removing this.

Comment: Also, the `LOCATION_HARDWARE` permission is for system use, don't ask for it. read here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#LOCATION_HARDWARE

Answer (score 1):

Quoted from here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions

> If your app targets Android 5.0 (API level 21) or higher and uses the
>   ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission in order to
>   receive location updates from the network or a GPS, respectively, you
>   must also explicitly declare that your app uses the
>   android.hardware.location.network or android.hardware.location.gps
>   hardware features.

Add it like this to your `AndroidManifest.xml` file outside of your `<application/>` tag:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network"/>

<application>
  ...
</application>
```

If the location feature is not a "must have" feature in your app in order for the app to work properly, also add this to the `uses-feature` tag - `android:required="false"`

**You still have to ask for location permission at runtime**

Comment: Hi, I added above permission in manifest also asked on runtime like given in code, it dose not ask for this permission. Again it crashed. @Hed Shafran

Comment: Did you try adding the `gps` uses-feature ?

Answer (score 0):

add ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION with targeting APIs 20 and below